# question on holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be a nonconstant holomorphic function in the unit disc {|z|<1} such that f(0)=1. Then it is necessary that

1. there are infinitely many points z in the unit disc such that |f(z)|=1
2. f is bounded
3. there are at most finitely many points z in the unit disc such that |f(z)|=1
4. f is a rational function.

Answer (score 2):

1. Note that $f$ is open, hence the image contains some open disk around $1$.
2. What about $f(z)=\frac1{1-z}$?
3. See 1.
4. What about f(z)=\exp(z)$?